# Cannot grant access to database_principal in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to run the following statement

```
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO database_principal
```

But I get the following error

> Cannot find the user 'database_principal', because it does not exist
>   or you do not have permission.

Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **database_principal** as came in your question, you have to `specify the principal` here is the correct template:

```
GRANT permission [ ,...n ]  
ON 
{  [ USER :: database_user ]
 | [ ROLE :: database_role ]
 | [ APPLICATION ROLE :: application_role ]
}
TO <database_principal> [ ,...n ]
   [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
   [ AS <database_principal> ]

<database_principal> ::=
  Database_user 
  | Database_role 
  | Application_role 
  | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_User 
  | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_Group 
  | Database_user_mapped_to_certificate 
  | Database_user_mapped_to_asymmetric_key 
  | Database_user_with_no_login
```

**Example:**

```
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO test_user;
```

> also if you want to enabling Query Notifications you have to do extra
>   configs [here](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/started-query-notifications-sql-server-2008-r2/1676/) is a useful link for it